# Data Annotation for MVC 5.0 is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

```
public class DropDownListViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SelectedId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public DropDownListViewModel Country { get; set; }
}
```

How get error message related to Country field. Currently it shows generic message saying 'Selectedid is required', But I want message related to country field.

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Isn't it suppose to tell you  that it is " required" like how it is?>

Comment: I guess you added using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations on the beginning of your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ErrorMessage` to have you own custom error message

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Custom Message")]
public string SelectedId { get; set; }
```

Comment: selectedid is generic and this class is used for every dropdown.

Comment: @Har, You cannot not apply it to the `Country` property - you must apply it to the property your binding to (and your control is binding to `SelectedId`, not `Country`)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the message in the view:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedId, "You must select a country")
```

The downside to this is if you had multiple error for `SelectedId` only the overridden message will be displayed.

Comment: @Har mark the answer as correct so it can help others in future